# validate the correct types of a collection with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm a little bit confused about how to check a collection(object) with the lodash `_.some()` function.

```
var x = {prop1: 800, prop2: 800, prop3: 'test'};

_.some(x, i => _.isNaN(i))
//false

_.some(x, _.isNaN)
//false
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I suggest, that the result of both some-fn are true because the prop3 is a string

Comment: That's not correct. `_.isNaN("string")` will return false, since it's not `NaN`. Try to run this statement in a console or so and you will see that.

Comment: Yes, you are right. How would you determinate if some of the collection is not a number. Or is it better to test if all(_.every) are numbers? I choose _.some because I thought it would be faster. then _.every

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you want to know if all of the properties are numbers, you can use this:

```
!_.some(x, i=> !_.isNumber(i))
```

I don't know about the perforamance differences of `_.some` and `_.every` but you could of course also use:

```
_.every(x, i=> _.isNumber(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

`_.isNaN('test')` returns `false`. It's a `string`.

`_.isString('test')` is what you're looking for.

```
_.some(x, (i) => {
    console.log(_.isString(i));
});

// false
// false
// true
```

Edit: Just seen your comment. If you want to check every value is a number you can do:

```
_.every(x, (i) => {
    console.log(i);
    return _.isNumber(i);
})

//false
```

Answer (score 0):

From the lodash doc
_.isNaN is based on [Number.isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) and is not the same as global [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) which returns true for undefined and other non-number values.

```
_.some(x, isNaN)
//true
```